# Error with dummy payment processor and email receipts

Tags: payment-processor, receipts

I set up a contribution page and trying it out I got an error message

> Payment Processor Error message :Failed to update contribution in
> database

and was taken back to the payment confirmation page, though the contribution appears to be recorded as "complete". It's the first time I've used email receipts on contribution pages (though they have been fine on event pages. Taking out the email receipt gets rid of the error. I was using the dummy payment processor, but if I switch to PayPal then all is fine so I'm guessing its a bug in the dummy payment processor.

I'm on CiviCRM 5.35.1 so an obvious thing to try is the latest version, but I don't have time to test that right now. I can work round it for demonstrating what I want to do by using PayPal and then refunding, but it's annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Could you check the Outbound email setting is not set to 'Disable Outbound Email'? And the Environment is production?

In case you don't want emails to go out you could set Outbound email to Redirect to Database

Comment: That's not the issue as there is no error and the email goes when I am using the PayPal payment processor and in plenty of other situations. The problem is only with the dummy payment processor selected.